# Add a gesture detector to a ViewPager

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, gesture

Is it possible to add a gesture detector to control the gestures over a `ViewPager`?
 I need to detect P and DOWN gestures in order to scale another View that is above the `ViewPager`.
 I tried with `OnTouchListener` but it destroyed the `horizontalScroll` of `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
Read this state it might be helpful for you